# List of Lists (summing indexes but need to skip certain indexes ('None' values)

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list of lists (`training_list`). There are 15 indexes per list. I need to sum up each index for each list e.g. list1 row[0] + list2 row[0] and so on.

I have created the function which allows me to do that - `def sums_list`. However I've run into a problem, when my code is summing each index it stops in index 2 because of the `None` value. This value is also contained in index 3 & 13.

I can't replace this `None` value, I need to keep as is. I'm looking to basically skip this and continue on to the next index.

```
training_list = [
    [22, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 10, 0.4122977346278317,
     0.10788834951456311, 0.038187702265372166, 0.8373381877022654,
     0.6119741100323625, 0, 0, 38, None, ' <=50K'],
    [28, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 5, 0.4122977346278317,
     0.12823624595469255, 0.3013349514563107, 0.8373381877022654,
     0.6119741100323625, 0, 0, 40, None, ' <=50K'],
    [30, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 13, 0.3351132686084142,
     0.09227346278317151, 0.033292880258899676, 0.8373381877022654,
     0.38802588996763754, 0, 0, 40, None, ' >50K'],
    [20, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 10, 0.4122977346278317,
     0.051941747572815535, 0.20230582524271845, 0.8373381877022654,
     0.6119741100323625, 0, 0, 20, None, ' >50K']
]
```

Code:

```
def sums_lists(list1, list2):
    try:
        sums_list = []
        for index in range(14):
            sums_list.append(list1[index]+list2[index])
    except:
        pass
    return sums_list

def make_averages(sums_list, total_int):

    try:
        average_list = []
        for value_int in sums_list:
            average_list.append(value_int/total_int)
    except:
        pass
    return average_list

def train_classifier(training_list):
    under_50k_sums_list = [0]*14 
    under_50k_count = 0 
    over_50k_sums_list = [0]*14 
    over_50k_count = 0 


    for row in training_list:
        if row[-1] == ' <=50K':

            under_50k_sums_list = sums_lists(under_50k_sums_list, row[:-1])
            under_50k_count += 1
        else: 
            over_50k_sums_list = sums_lists(over_50k_sums_list, row[:-1])
            over_50k_count += 1

            under_50k_averages_list = make_averages(under_50k_sums_list, under_50k_count)
            over_50k_averages_list = make_averages(over_50k_sums_list, over_50k_count)


        classifier_list = make_averages(sums_lists(under_50k_averages_list, over_50k_averages_list),2)

    return classifier_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def sums_lists(list1, list2):
    zipped = zip(list1,list2)
    result = []
    for item in zipped[:-1]:
        if None not in item:
            result.append(sum(item))
    return result
```

If only the last parts can be strings, you can skip that part in your summation.

Comment: Hi Angel, thanks for the response, so your code leaves out the None which is great but when it gets to the under_50k_sums_list - the list only contains index 0 and index 1. So you've definitely helped me but its the same issue at the next step of the code

Comment: You mean because of the strings like '<=50K' for example.
You should modify your question, to exactly mention what your problems are.